# Adjusting slider image & content for responsive design

Tags: html, css

Im facing a very basic problem with css. I have slider with tabs over image at bottom. Problem is if my image size match with screen or resolution then it shows proper. But if screen size gets low then it changes it's position. See below 2 images.

below 1366px resolution
[image: Screen resolution 1366px]

1600px and above
[image: Screen resolution 1600px and above]

On 1600px it looks ok but in lesser resolution it looks worst.  Please help to resolve it. following is my code

css

```
.master-slider{
    width:100%;
    height:567px
}

.master-slider-inner{
    width:100%;
    max-width:1600px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto
}

#slideshow { 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width:100%;
    height:567px;
}

#slideshow > .slideImg { 
    position: absolute; 
}

#slideshow img{
    width:100%;
}

.banner-links {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.banner-links-inner {
    width:auto;
    max-width:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.banner-nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.banner-nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.banner-nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px 50px 15px 50px;
    display: block;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}


<!--master-slider-starts--><div class="master-slider">
            <!--master-slider-inner-starts--><div class="master-slider-inner">
                <div id="slideshow">
                    <div class="slideImg">
                        <img src="images/Gift-a-spa.jpg" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="slideImg">
                        <img src="images/Gift-A-Shopping.jpg" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="slideImg">
                        <img src="images/Gift-a-Skill-Learn.jpg" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="slideImg">
                        <img src="images/Indoor-Sports.jpg" />
                    </div>

                    <!--banner-links-starts--><div class="banner-links">
            <div class="banner-links-inner">
                <!--banner-nav-starts--><ul class="banner-nav">
                <li><a class="current" href="#">Helicopter Tour Mumbai</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">JBL Flip II Offer</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dominos 20% Off</a></li>
                <li class="no-border"><a class="no-border" href="#">Paragliding</a></li>
            </ul><!--banner-nav-ends-->
            </div>
        </div><!--bannner-links-ends-->
                </div>
            </div><!--master-slider-inner-ends-->
        </div><!--master-slider-ends-->
```

Comment: can i have live url please?

Comment: Your image is getting smaller (it responses to the width of your screen) and the container still has the same height set by you.

Comment: @pavelccz so how to resolve it?

Comment: Do you want your image to always show in full width? Or do you want to cropp it (slice the sides and keep it's height)?

Comment: @pavelccz  The last width for full size image is 1600px. After that it's size gets fixed. But screen under 1600px it should maintain it's width & height as per resolution

Comment: @HiralSuvagya here is the live site link http://surajcreator.com/brandstik/index.html

Comment: Try implementing something like this http://www.slidesjs.com/

Comment: @pavelccz The link  you given is easy to maintain because there tabs links are not over image. Is it not possible by having it over image?

Comment: It is easy to style it so it is over the image. Just add `#slides{position: relative;}` and position absolutely the controls and style them as you want. Nobody is going to give you the perfect plugin, you have to play with it a little bit. This one is very easy. You have to try, then come here if you fail and tell us what you could not do while trying. But just try it on your own first.

Comment: The main thing about this plugin is that it counts the height of the container so is as high as the images. That is the thing you want here.